# Apache Camel throws java.lang.NullPointerException on scheduling ftp endpoint using quartz scheduler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to use `camel-quartz2` for scheduling FTP endpoint in spring boot application. But however on the start of the application it's throwing Null Pointer Exception.

Below is the code snippet for FTP URI

```
private final String NBP_GMI_TRADE_DAILY_FTP_CONNECTION_URI = "ftp://<username>@<hostip>/NBP/GMI/?password=<password>"
        + "&disconnect=true"
        + "&idempotent=true"
        + "&idempotentKey=${file:name}-${file:size}"
        + "&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true"
        + "&filter=#nbpGmiTradeDailyFileFilter"
        + "&passiveMode=true"
        + "&binary=true"
        + "&recursive=true"
        + "scheduler=quartz2"
        + "&scheduler.cron=0+0/2+*+?+*+SUN,SAT+*";
```

FTP Camel Configuration

```
from(NBP_GMI_TRADE_DAILY_FTP_CONNECTION_URI)
    .routeId("NBP_GMI_TRADE_DAILY_FTP_ROUTE")
    .choice()
    .when(simple("${body} != null")).setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple("${file:name.noext}_${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS}.${file:ext}")).to("file://{{user.home}}/NBP/data/daily/backup/?fileName=${date:now:yyyyMMdd}/${file:name}").end();
```

On Application start, I'm getting below exception

```
        org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:225) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:52) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
        at com.fis.derivatives.utility.nbp.Application.main(Application.java:36) [classes/:na]
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler.startScheduler(DefaultScheduledPollConsumerScheduler.java:145) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.startScheduler(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:456) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer.doStart(FtpConsumer.java:67) ~[camel-ftp-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startService(DefaultCamelContext.java:3514) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3831) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartRouteConsumers(DefaultCamelContext.java:3767) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.safelyStartRouteServices(DefaultCamelContext.java:3687) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartOrResumeRoutes(DefaultCamelContext.java:3451) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3305) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:202) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3089) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:3085) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:3108) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:3085) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:3022) ~[camel-core-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.maybeStart(RoutesCollector.java:242) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:217) ~[camel-spring-boot-2.19.3.jar:2.19.3]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
```

I using below version of spring-boot and apache camel respectively

```
spring-boot: 1.5.6.RELEASE
apache-camel: 2.19.3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw that in your endpoint string you have : `"scheduler=quartz2"`, this should be `"&scheduler=quartz2"`. Could you also check if you have included the `camel-quartz2` or `camel-quartz2-starter` dependency?